# Excel - Find min date given a condition

Tags: excel

I have the following data and need to extract the row of the minimum date for each year 2017 and 2016. This formula should be generic since I will have a different number of rows each time I use this sheet.

```
DATE_ID     Año
01-mar-17   2017
02-mar-17   2017
03-mar-17   2017
04-mar-17   2017
05-mar-17   2017
26-feb-16   2016
27-feb-16   2016
28-feb-16   2016
29-feb-16   2016
01-mar-16   2016
02-mar-16   2016
```

If I type just MIN(), it will return February 26th / 2016 and I need it to identify the year also. Result must be March 1st and February 26th for each year in the table.

Thanks!!

Comment: Try an if condition to check the year first.then add the main function

Comment: A pivot table could do this also

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dates are real dates not the text and your dates in the range A2:A11, then try this **Array Formula** which will require special key stroke **Ctrl + Shift + Enter** to confirm the formula instead of Enter alone.

```
=MIN(IF(YEAR($A$2:$A$11)=2017,$A$2:$A$11))
```

Confirm with **Ctrl + Shift + Enter**
Instead of hard coding the 2017 in the formula, you can put the year in a cell and refer that cell in the formula.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all,

Definitely, a pivot table with the year as a column and the min date as value did it.

Answer (score -1):

```
=if(year(A:A) =B1,Min(A:A) )
```

Try this ,I am not sure whether this will work,I haven't tested it. You may need to initialise the formula as an array function

Comment: Hi, Sivaprasath. It does not work, It returns February 26th. The IF statement does not alter the MIN search. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Did you initialise the formula as an array function?

Comment: The formula is faulty.